# ResourcesNotFoundException in the devices below marshmallow for fused location provider

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

The fused location provider works fine in android marshmallow but it fails to install the versions below it. The code, build.gradle, manifest and build error are below. Please have a look.

My code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lblLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblLocation);
    btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
    btnStartLocationUpdates = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLocationUpdates);

     // Check for permission
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this, // Activity
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
        }

    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        Log.i("playservice", checkPlayServices()+"");
        // Building the GoogleApi client
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            displayLocation();
        }
    });

}

private void displayLocation() {

    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

        lblLocation.setText(latitude + ", " + longitude);
    } else {
        lblLocation.setText("(Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device)");
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient");

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connected!");
    createLocationRequest();
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    Log.i(TAG, " Location: " + mLastLocation);
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(final LocationResult locationResult) {
            Log.i("onLocationResult",locationResult + "");

            btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    lblLocation.setText(locationResult.getLocations() + "");
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationAvailability(LocationAvailability locationAvailability) {
            Log.i("onLocationAvailability", "onLocationAvailability: isLocationAvailable =  " + locationAvailability.isLocationAvailable());
        }
    }, null);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
            + result.getErrorCode());
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        Log.i(TAG, "mGoogleApiClient.connect()");
    }
}
```

**Build.gradle(Module:app)**
PS. I've tested using build version 21.1.2 as well but no luck

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bbeck.bbeck.fuseapinew"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

Below is the permission I've used

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

**Error log:**

```
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987): Process: com.test.test.fuseapinew, PID: 14987
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.test.fuseapinew/com.test.test.fuseapinew.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020052
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020052
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3376)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1872)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:374)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:202)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:711)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:131)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:151)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:31)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:55)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:205)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at com.test.test.fuseapinew.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    ... 11 more
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:986)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:930)
08-07 15:00:28.901: E/AndroidRuntime(14987):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3372)
```

Comment: gms 11.0.4 needs com.android.support at least in 25.2.0

Comment: @Selvin this fatal error is happening in android OS 4 even after having com.android.support 26.0.0